# Table access full instead of using partition in oracle while using parallel

Tags: oracle11g

I am using below query on a table XYZ which which is 3 TB . And one partition(Day wise partition) size is around 90GB. 
issue is its taking parallel only and doing a FTS instead of single Partition access .
When we remove parallel its doing a singlr partition acces .

Kindly help, we need to use parallel and should go for single partition instead of FTS.

```
enter code here

   SELECT /*+PARALLEL(A,4)*/
    MSISDN,
   CALL_START_DATE,
   DEST_NUMBER,
   IN_CALL_TYPE,
   CELL_ID,
   DEVICE_ID,
  CDR_TYPE,
  CALL_DURATION,
  CALL_CHARGES,
  COS_ID,
  USAGE_ALCS_ID,
  DISC_ALCS_ID,
  SUBSTR(BAL_INFO,
    INSTR(BAL_INFO, '*', INSTR(BAL_INFO, '1*CORE BALANCE'), 3) + 1,
    INSTR(BAL_INFO, '*', INSTR(BAL_INFO, '1*CORE BALANCE'), 4) - 1 -
    INSTR(BAL_INFO, '*', INSTR(BAL_INFO, '1*CORE BALANCE'), 3)) CORE_REV,
  SUBSTR(BAL_INFO,
    INSTR(BAL_INFO, '*', INSTR(BAL_INFO, '*3*PROMOTIONAL BALANCE 1'), 4) + 1,
    INSTR(BAL_INFO, '*', INSTR(BAL_INFO, '*3*PROMOTIONAL BALANCE 1'), 5) - 1 -
    INSTR(BAL_INFO, '*', INSTR(BAL_INFO, '*3*PROMOTIONAL BALANCE 1'), 4)) PROMO_REV,
    SUBSTR(BAL_INFO,
    INSTR(BAL_INFO, '*', INSTR(BAL_INFO, '*271*PROMO BAL V7'), 4) + 1,
    INSTR(BAL_INFO, '*', INSTR(BAL_INFO, '*271*PROMO BAL V7'), 5) - 1 -
    INSTR(BAL_INFO, '*', INSTR(BAL_INFO, '*271*PROMO BAL V7'), 4)) PROMO_BAL_V7,
     SUBSTR(BAL_INFO,
    INSTR(BAL_INFO, '*', INSTR(BAL_INFO, '*313*PROMO BAL V4'), 4) + 1,
    INSTR(BAL_INFO, '*', INSTR(BAL_INFO, '*313*PROMO BAL V4'), 5) - 1 -
    INSTR(BAL_INFO, '*', INSTR(BAL_INFO, '*313*PROMO BAL V4'), 4)) PROMO_BAL_V4,
   0' FREE_MINS,
   '0' FREE_SMS,
   '0' OFF_PEAK,
  '0' PROMO_SEC,
  '0' V2VL_2300_0700
   FROM xyz
   WHERE CDR_TYPE in ('VOICE', '0', '4', 'SMS')
    AND CALL_START_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('20140501', 'YYYYMMDD') AND
   TO_DATE('20140501235959', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
    AND NVL(TOT_NON_CURCY_CHRG, 0) = 0;
```

Comment: Can you simplify the query, for example by removing most of the `SELECT` list?  Also, can you post the good and bad explain plans, using `explain plan for ...` and `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);`?

Answer (score 0):

what is **A** in snippet below:

```
SELECT /*+PARALLEL(A,4)*/....
```

I don't see any aliases A. Your hint is incorrect (or posted code is incomplete) .
Dosc are [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/hintsref.htm#PFGRF95144)

Comment: Alias got missed while posting . Assume that Alias is present .